# Map Material design icon to Drawable folder in Android application

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-icons

Google has released a set of [icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) for Material design. However each folder like drawable-xhdpi in this has 4 different sizes of each icon. If some one wants to use them in his/her android application which one to use for each density type

1. drawable-hdpi
2. drawable-xhdpi
3. drawable-xxhdpi
4. drawable-xxxhdpi

Can anybody help me which icons to use here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the type of icon you need. The developers guide says about iconography that for example notification icons should be 24dp, action bar icons 32dp, small icons 16dp and so on.